# Meter una lista dentro de otra en Android (Java)

Tags: java, android

a ver: tengo una lista de mascotas (en principio todo esto es en local, nada de bases de datos), cada mascota que tiene esta lista debe tener asociados una serie de alarmas y recordatorios. Por un lado tengo dos adapter, uno de las mascotas y otro de las alarmas, la lista de mascotas la tengo plasmada en un fragment pero ya no se como hacer para que cuando yo pulse una mascota se muestre una lista de recordatorios u otra...

El adapter de las mascotas:

```
package com.isaac.appet;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

RecyclerView rvPetResume;
ArrayList<Pets> pets = new ArrayList<>();

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    rvPetResume = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.rvPetResume);

    Pets perro1 = new Pets();
    perro1.setPetName("Alegría");
    perro1.setPetUrlImage("https://nuevavida-adopciones.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/tronko-adoptar-perro-adopcion-protectora-nuevavida-madrid-300x300.jpg");

    Pets erizo1 = new Pets();
    erizo1.setPetName("Sonic");
    erizo1.setPetUrlImage("https://www.curiosfera.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Qu%C3%A9-es-el-erizo-y-sus-caracter%C3%ADsticas.jpg");

    pets.add(perro1);
    pets.add(erizo1);
    pets.add(perro1);
    pets.add(erizo1);
    pets.add(perro1);
    pets.add(erizo1);
    pets.add(perro1);
    pets.add(erizo1);

    PetsAdapter adapter = new PetsAdapter(getActivity(), pets, R.layout.item_animal_resume);
    rvPetResume.setAdapter(adapter);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

    rvPetResume.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

}
}
```

La clase Pets:

```
    package com.isaac.appet;

public class Pets {

    private String petName;

    public String getPetUrlImage() {
        return petUrlImage;
    }

    public void setPetUrlImage(String petUrlImage) {
        this.petUrlImage = petUrlImage;
    }

    private String petUrlImage;

    public String getPetName() {
        return petName;
    }

    public void setPetName(String petName) {
        this.petName = petName;
    }

}
```

El Adapter de las Alarmas:

```
package com.isaac.appet;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AlarmsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlarmsAdapter.AlarmsViewHolder> {

Context context;
int resource;
ArrayList<Alarms> alarms;

public AlarmsAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<Alarms> alarms, int resource) {

    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resource;
    this.alarms = alarms;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public AlarmsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resource, viewGroup, false);
    AlarmsViewHolder alarmsViewHolder = new AlarmsViewHolder(itemView);
    return alarmsViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AlarmsViewHolder alarmsViewHolder, int i) {

    alarmsViewHolder.bindAlarms(alarms.get(i));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return alarms.size();
}

public class AlarmsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tvAlarmTitle;
    TextView tvAlarmDesc;
    TextView tvAlarmTime;

    public AlarmsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvAlarmTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAlarmTitle);
        tvAlarmDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAlarmDesc);
        tvAlarmTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAlarmTime);

    }

    public void bindAlarms (Alarms alarm) {

        tvAlarmTitle.setText(alarm.getTitle());
        tvAlarmDesc.setText(alarm.getDesc());
        tvAlarmTime.setText(alarm.getTime());

    }
}

}
```

La clase Alarms:

```
    package com.isaac.appet;

public class Alarms {

    String title;
    String desc;
    String time;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

Pues me gustaría que cada vez que yo creo una mascota, dentro tuviera sus propias alarmas creadas para dicha mascotas, y que se mostraran en mi Home Fragment que es donde tengo la lista de mascotas, no se si me he explicado.

Comment: Y la clase pets cual es?

Comment: Perdón que no las he añadido, ahi he añadido ambas clases, la Pets y la de Alarms

Comment: Y porque sencillamente la clase pets no contiene una lista de alarmas? (no soy experto en java para android, pero tu problema parece de clases, sin importar el donde). Y otra cosa, estas programando en java para android. Android studio es solo la ide.

Comment: @gbianchi y como especifico los campos que quiero que tenga Alarma? no se si te refieres a que elimine la clase Alarm y dentro de Pets construya otro atributo con una lista de alarmas o que manteniendo ambas clases cree una lista. Seguramente lo que he dicho no tenga mucho sentido, pero soy muy nuevo en esto de programar

Comment: La clase pets, tendra dentro de sus propiedas, una que sea ArrayList<Alarms> alarms;.. de esa manera cada mascota va a tener su alarma.

Comment: Vale, eso lo entiendo, pero después como le digo al Adapter de Pets que me muestre las alarmas del perro que sea? ¿Tendría que crear las alarmas manualmente (de momento ya que no he implementado nada para crearlas) en el código y asignarla a la mascota en cuestión?

Comment: Por supuesto.. tenes que crear alarmas que sean del perro.. o del animal que corresponda.. y cuando muestras, muestras las alarmas para el animal que hayas elegido.

Comment: te invito al [chat] si queres, y ahi podremos darte una mano entre varios

Comment: @gbianchi he entrado, seguimos por ahí muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías establecer una relación del tipo "Animales tienen alarmas" trayendo un flujo más limpio a la hora de trabajar, ya que si puedes asignar a una mascota una lista de alarmas.

```
public class Pets {

    private String petName;
    private ArrayList<Alarms> alarms;

    public String getPetUrlImage() {
        return petUrlImage;
    }

    public void setPetUrlImage(String petUrlImage) {
        this.petUrlImage = petUrlImage;
    }

    private String petUrlImage;

    public String getPetName() {
        return petName;
    }

    public void setPetName(String petName) {
        this.petName = petName;
    }

    public ArrayList<Alarms> getAlarms() {
        return alarms;
    }

    public void setAlarms(ArrayList<Alarms> alarms) {
        this.alarms = alarms;
    }
}
```

Entonces a la hora de hacer click en una mascota simplemente cargarías tu adaptador obteniendo las alarmas a esa mascota.

```
//Click en una mascota
...
ArrayList<Alarms> alarmas =  mascotaCliqueada.getAlarms();

//desplegar esa informacion en el adaptador
...
```

**Editado**
Ejemplo del procedimiento aseguir.

```
Pets miMascota = new Pets();
ArrayList<Alarms> alarmas = new ArrayList<>();
Alarm alarma1 = new Alarm(); //Creamos una alarma y procedemos a llenar sus datos.
...
//Asignar la alarma creada a la lista
alarmas.add(alarma1);
...
//Agregamos la lista de alarma a la mascota
miMascota.setAlarms(alarmas);
...
```

Comment: Después solo tendría que crear una alarma de ejemplo y asignarla a una mascota no? ¿De qué forma podría mostrarlo en adapter? Tengo un pequeño cacao

Comment: @Isaac Solo bastaría con añadir una lista de alarmas ya creadas a una instancia de una mascota con el método setAlarms();

Comment: Pero para mostrarla en el adapter no tengo que hacer nada especial? ¿No tendría que crear un nuevo adapter para las alarmas que me las muestre en el segundo recyclerview?

Comment: Vi que ya tienes un adapter creado, si ese adapter funciona solo tienes que pasarle las alarmas para que las muestre. Obtendrías las alarmas haciendo uso de getAlarms() en una instancia de Pets

Comment: ¿Uso el Adapter de Pets o el de Alarms? No se a cual te refieres, por si puedo descartar uno de ellos

Comment: Si lo que necesitas es mostrar alarmas entonces el que debes usar es el de Alarms

Comment: Cuando he creado la lista, he creado la alarma y se la he querido settear a una mascota, no me deja, me dice: setAlarms
(java.util.ArrayList<com.isaac.appet.Alarms>)
in Pets cannot be applied
to
(com.isaac.appet.Alarms)

Comment: Estas intentando setear una alarma pero realmente lo que debes de setear es la lista de alarmas si ves el ejemplo que puse arriba en "Editado" en mi respuestas verás como lo puedes hacer